# Custom Adapter with Search Not working

Tags: java, android

I tried to add textwatcher with filter class but it do not work plz help. I get the json array through the server using the url. the search(filter) doesnt work well.

public class CallDetails extends Activity {

```
SessionManager session;
ArrayList<Drivers> driverList = new ArrayList<Drivers>();
private List<Drivers> driverlist = null;
ListView listview;
ImageButton btback;
DriverAdapter dadapter;
String uid;
String name;
String email;
String odtyp;
static String oid;      
Drivers driver;

private EditText editTextFilter;
private static String OUTBOX_URL ="";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.calldetails);
    Intent i = getIntent();  
    oid =i.getStringExtra("orderId");
    odtyp =i.getStringExtra("ordertype");       
    OUTBOX_URL ="http://www.gdrive.com/api/calldetails.php?id="+oid;

    //managing session...
    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());      
    HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails(); 
    name = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_NAME);        
    email = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_EMAIL);
    uid = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_UID);
    btback =(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnBack);        
    btback.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    // Locate the EditText in listview_main.xml
    editTextFilter = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextFilter);
    editTextFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            String text = editTextFilter.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
            dadapter.filter(text);
        }
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                int arg2, int arg3){ /* to do*/ }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) { /*to do*/ }
    }); 


    //populating view with data...
    //driverList = new ArrayList<Drivers>();
    new JSONAsyncTask().execute(OUTBOX_URL);
    listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.drlist);         
    dadapter = new DriverAdapter(CallDetails.this, R.layout.list_item, driverList);
    listview.setItemsCanFocus(false);
    listview.setAdapter(dadapter);
    //populating list ends


    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), driverList.get(position).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();              
        }
    }); 
    }
    public void back(View v){
         Intent back = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SafetyDrive.class);
         startActivity(back);
         finish();
}


private class DriverAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Drivers> {
    Context context;
    int Resource;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ArrayList<Drivers> driverList = new ArrayList<Drivers>();

    public DriverAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,ArrayList<Drivers> drs) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, drs);
        //inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        Resource = layoutResourceId;
        driverList = drs;           
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //Log.d("in ", "view start");
        View item = convertView;
        DriverWrapper DriverWrapper = null;         
        if (item == null) {
            DriverWrapper = new DriverWrapper();
            item = inflater.inflate(Resource, null);                
            DriverWrapper.ename = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.textName);
            DriverWrapper.ephone = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.textPhone);                
            DriverWrapper.mkcall = (ImageButton) item.findViewById(R.id.btnphone);              
            item.setTag(DriverWrapper);
        } else {
            DriverWrapper = (DriverWrapper) item.getTag();
        }
        Drivers driver = driverList.get(position);
        DriverWrapper.ename.setText("Name: " + driver.getName());
        DriverWrapper.ephone.setText("Phone: " + driver.getPhone());
        final String dp = driver.getPhone().trim();

        DriverWrapper.mkcall.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //making call..
                //Log.e("no is", dp);
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" +dp));
                //callIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(callIntent);  
                //finish();
            }
        });

        return item;
    }
    class DriverWrapper {
        TextView ename;
        TextView ephone;
        ImageButton mkcall;
        //ImageButton msg;  
    }

    // Filter Class     
    public void filter(String charText) {
        charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        driverList.clear();
        if (charText.length() == 0) {               
            driverList.addAll(driverList);
        } else {
            for (Drivers driver : driverList) {
                if (driver.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText)) {
                    driverList.add(driver);
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

class JSONAsyncTask extends AsyncTask {

```
    ProgressDialog dialog;      
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(CallDetails.this);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading, please wait");
        dialog.show();
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            //Log.d("in at-", "asynctask");
            HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            // StatusLine stat = response.getStatusLine();
            int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if (status == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);                 

                JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);                    
                JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("drivers");                   
               if(jarray.length()!=0){
                   for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {                      
                        JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);                    
                        Drivers driver = new Drivers();     
                        driver.setPhone(object.getString("phone"));
                        driver.setName(object.getString("emp_name"));
                        driverList.add(driver);                             
                    }                       
               }else{
                    driver = new Drivers();     
                    driver.setPhone(" ");
                    driver.setName(" No Driver Place yet");
                    driverList.add(driver);
                }
                return true;
            }

        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        dialog.cancel();
        btback.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        dadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        if(result == false)
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to fetch data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

}

public class Drivers {

```
private String name;
private String phone;

public Drivers() {

}

public Drivers(String name, String phone) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.phone = phone;

}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}
```

}

Comment: what do you mean the search(filter) doesnt work well. ..is it working or not

Comment: What is your output for this code?

Comment: output is fine its displays complete result set, but when I try to filter on name there is no output , there is no error as well. (shows complete list very well)

Comment: actually it wont filter because youve cleared the driverList and then in the else statement you loop to driverList which is already empty. the only thing you can do is create a backup list for the driversList and then use the backup list to get all data for filtering.

Answer (score 0):

actually it wont filter because youve cleared the driverList and then in the else statement you loop to driverList which is already empty. the only thing you can do is create a backup list for the driversList and then use the backup list to get all data for filtering to the driverList.

Example Here:

```
// here is the backuplist
ArrayList<Drivers> backupList = new ArrayList<Drivers>();
   // Filter Class     
public void filter(String charText) {
    charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
    // actually its easy to just clear the backup list
    // but due to reasons where users press backspace you have to load backup list only once
    if(backupList.isEmpty()) {
        backupList.addAll(driverList);
    }
    driverList.clear();
    if (charText.length() == 0) {
        driverList.addAll(backupList);
    } else {
        for (Drivers driver : backupList) {
            if (driver.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText)) {
                driverList.add(driver);
            }
        }
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: oh thats good, will you accept this answer if it helps you? :)